# Clone a function then delete it

Tags: javascript

I want to clone a function, but I need to delete the original.

```
let obj={};
obj.funct=function funct() { console.log('test');}
let clone={};
clone.funct=obj.funct.bind({});
delete obj.funct
```

But the function is deleted in both objects.

Any idea ? Maybe a ref or val problem ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Can't reproduce -> https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/pfpdxs4x/

Comment: I don't see a problem here `obj.funct()` will have a error (*since it was removed*) and `clone.funct()` works propertly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using inside a loop and was cloning the same reference object, so deleting the same var.

Sorry for my mistake and thank you for showing me that the code runs correctly.

ie: you can add all -1 that you want. Sorry again

Answer (score -1):

When you pass the value to `clone.funct`, you're really just passing a reference of the original function.  Kill the original function and the reference goes to nothing.

One way to sever the parity would be stringify the initial function, then use a function constructor to create the clone:

```js
const obj={};
obj.funct=function funct(a,b) { console.log(a,b);}
const clone={};
const functString = obj.funct.toString();
clone.funct= new Function('return (' + functString + ')(...arguments)');
delete obj.funct

 console.log('Original:',obj.funct)
 console.log('Cloned:',clone.funct)
 clone.funct('hello', 'there')
```

Comment: Uhm, thats what `bind` does, it returns a new function.